# How do i get a file from a writable node stream?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, qr-code, node-streams

**What am i doing**
So I'm trying to reply to a command interaction with a QR code, and I don't want to save the file to the directory of the bot and then send it that way, instead, I have the QR code text, and I'm using the QR Code package to convert it into a QR Code, and now I'm trying to write the file to a node stream.

**What is the problem**
The problem is I don't know how to access that file, since when I try to use `{ files: [returned.qrcode] }` it doesn't send an image attachment.

**More information**
Its a writable stream, dont know how to get the file from the stream, it returns a normal writable stream

**The code**

The code for getting the QR Code and writing it to a stream

```js
        const id = uuid.v4();
        const temp_secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({
            name: "VikkiVuk (2FA): " + id
        });

        let newUser = await new factorschema({
            id: id,
            temp_secret: temp_secret.base32,
            secret: "waiting"
        }).save()

        await schema.updateOne({ userid: user.id }, { uuid: id })

        let data
        const filestream = new Stream.Writable()
        qrcode.toFileStream(filestream, temp_secret.otpauth_url)

        const readableStream = new Stream.Readable()
        readableStream.push(null)
        readableStream.pipe(filestream)

        filestream.end()

        return { userid: id, temp_secret: temp_secret, qrcode: readableStream }
```

Command code (the part where I try and send the attachment)

```js
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true })
        const result = await handler.register2FA(interaction.user)
        console.log(result) // logs a stream, its not undefined
        await interaction.editReply({ content: "Scan this qr code", ephemeral: true, files: [result.qrcode]})
```

Logged stream:

```
Readable {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [ [Writable] ],
    flowing: true,
    ended: true,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    constructed: true,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: true,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: true,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
  },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    end: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onend] },
    data: [Function: ondata]
  },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

Comment: *Does not work* Details? what are the errors? what type of stream is this what does it return?? "node stream" as such is nothing

Comment: Its a writable stream if you cant read by the code i added, as i said, i dont know how to get the file from the stream, it returns a normal writable stream.

Comment: As per your output the stream is still inside a keyv which is qrcode try result.qrcode.qrcode ( if you didnt log result instead of result.qrcode that is )

Comment: Now it gives me this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
`

Comment: Also i did log the result instead of result.qrcode

Comment: Edited the question with the qrcode output instead of result output

Comment: Please refer to the edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, transform your stream like so:

```js
async function createStream() { 
const stream = new Transform({
      transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        this.push(chunk)
        callback()
      }
    })
 await qrcode.toFileStream(filestream, temp_secret.otpauth_url)
}
return stream;
```

The [MessageAttachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment) constructor available to discord.js accepts writeable streams you may convert your stream to a `.png` using the constructor like so:

```js
    const {
        MessageAttachment
    } = require("discord.js");
    let qrcode = createStream();
    const x = new MessageAttachment(qrcode, 'QRCode.png') // further attach it like so:
    await interaction.editReply({
        content: "Skeniraj ovaj qr code dole.",
        ephemeral: true,
        files: [x]
    })
```

Constructor accepts the following three parameters, Where attachment would be your writable stream , name would be your filename and data would be the [APIAttachment object](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#attachment-object)  which also offers you options such as width and height of that image / specifics listed in the documentation. 
[image: Constructor]

Comment: So ive tried turning it into a readable stream, it gets rid of the error, but then it doesnt send the file... And if its a writable stream it gives me this error: `The file must be a valid string buffer or a stream`

Comment: Could you try logging result.qrcode to see if its a valid stream

Comment: I did, it is a valid stream.

Comment: The constructor for sure accepts any valid stream could you share the output with me?

Comment: I edited the question with the output since i cant send everything here.

Comment: Added how to create your stream properly so its readable, please try that out.

Comment: Im confused, where do i have to put the createStream function in the handler or in the command?

Comment: Also how do i return the stream property outside of the function?

Comment: The function itself returns a stream so you just need to call it when you attach it

Comment: Now it gives me two errors: Its a promise{ undefined} now, and `The _write() method is not implemented`

Comment: Okay i added await now its undefined

Comment: Put the return stream inside the function now it gives me the write method is not implemented error again

Comment: Okay i removed the filestream writable stream and changed the qrcode thing to write to the stream inside the function now were back at the start and no errors and doesnt send the file.

Comment: Nevermind! I changed the ephemeral thing to false it works now! Thanks!

Comment: Figured out your error! It isn't awaiting cuz it's an interaction, please use `interaction#defer()` to continue using ephemeral.